# Beanstalk App failing to connect to RDS (using hibernate)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a simple Jersey REST api to the beanstalk using Maven. 
I created an environment in my aws with a RDS. I also made the RDS public so that i can connect to it by through command line using "mysql -h -u xxxx -p" command. Below is my config for hibernate.

```
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>        
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://aws:3306/jersey</property>                                                               
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

However, I get following: error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:391)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
```

Is there something I need to allow connections. The RDS already shows a group that should allow my app to talk to it.

Any idea? It worked locally when I used local mysql and I have updated the hibernate to use the aws env

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not certain from the above configuration if you have obscured the real values with dummy ones. However you should ideally be using the environment variables that Elastic Beanstalk automatically populates, such as RDS_HOSTNAME and RDS_PORT.